# OCMClassMock ignore class

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

I am writing some unit tests where I want to ignore backend calls while the tests run, so ignore AFURLConnectionOperation. I am using OCMClassMock and expected that to behave as a nice-mock. Calls made to any objects of type AFURLConnectionOperation should be ignored without producing and exception. That doesn't seem to be the case. Calls are not ignored. What am I doing wrong?

> OCMClassMock([AFURLConnectionOperation class])

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you work with AFURLConnectionOperation in code. Does your code call class methods? or instantiate each time?

This example is in case you use instance methods:

```
id mockAF = OCMClassMock([AFURLConnectionOperation class]);
OCMStub([mockAF initWithRequest:[OCMArg any]]).andReturn(mockAF);
```

You need to call this for each test you run (i.e. in setup method).

This will return the mock object any time a new instance is instantiated and that should catch your network calls.

Comment: My code instantiates each time so this doesn't work. I will have to inject the objects to make it work.

Comment: So this will work. In my example mockAF can be used to mock both class methods and then instance methods. You can stub it to receive any of the instance calls and then inject it to your test (or any other architect you use
If you post your snippet I can maybe demonstrate better.